# Android. SwipeRefreshLayout перестает отображаться после смены ориентации экрана

Tags: android

SwipeRefreshLayout находится внутри фрагмента. После смены ориентации на ландшафтную и пересоздания фрагмента анимированный значек SwipeRefreshLayout перестает отрисовываться, но при этом OnRefreshListener срабатывает.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вот в чем: индикатор отрисовывался с отступом сверху, равным высоте ActionBar. Если прочесть высоту ActionBar таким образом, то один раз высота считается корректно, а после смены ориентации будем всегда получать ноль.

```
int actionBarHeight = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
```

**Корректный способ узнать высоту ActionBar:**

```
int actionBarSize;
        if (getActivity().getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)){
            actionBarSize = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать координаты индикатора после инициализации SwipeRefreshLayout:

```
int yCoordOfIndicator=0;
swipeRef.setProgressViewEndTarget(false, yCoordOfIndicator);
```

Comment: Ошибка оказалась в неожиданном месте...

Comment: @Evgeniy и в каком же?

Comment: я опубликовал ответ

Comment: @Evgeniy, чрез пару дней сможете свой ответ отметить как правильный (галочкой под стрелками голосования за вопрос).